# Convolution of image with kernel gives white output

Tags: image, image-processing, convolution, gaussian

I've a code that filters image with 3x3 Gaussian kernel but the output is white. GuassianFilter function works(output is correct) but there is problem in convolution function.

What would be the problem? I checked code again but couldn't solve this.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
path="funny_hats.jpg"
inputImage = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


def GaussianFilter(img): 
    #generating 3x3 kernel
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), dtype='float64')
    size = 3
    mean = int(size/2)
    sigma = 1 # standart deviation is 1
    sumAll = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            kernel[i,j] = math.exp(-1* ((math.pow( (i-mean)/sigma, 2.0) + (math.pow((j-mean)/sigma, 2.0)) ) / (2* math.pow(sigma,2)) )) / (sigma * math.pow(2*math.pi, 1/2))
            sumAll += kernel[i,j]
    # normalizing kernel
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            kernel[i,j] /= sumAll
    # Filter image with created kernel   
    img = convolution(img, kernel) # filtered image
    print(img)
    cv2.imshow('aa', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def convolution(img, dest):
    res = img
    [h,w] = img.shape
    [kh, kw] = dest.shape # kernel shape
    kr = int(kh/2) # kernel radius
    res = np.zeros(img.shape)

    for i in range(0+kr,h-kr):
        for j in range(0+kr,w-kr):
            for k in range(-1 * kr, kr + 1):
                for m in range(-1 * kr, kr + 1):
                    res[i,j] += dest[k,m]*img[i+k, j+m]
    res[:,0] = res[:, 1]
    res[:,w-1] = res[:, w-2]
    res[0,:] = res[1,:]
    res[h-1,:] = res[h-2,:]
    return res


GaussianFilter(inputImage)
```

Comment: Your input, I presume, is uint8 array, your output is a double-float array. Likely OpenCV image display does the same as MATLAB image display: doubles are shown such that [0,1] range maps to black-white, anything above 1 will be white. Divide your result by 255 before display.

Comment: Thank you, I normalized first the res variable, then changed to uint8. works well now.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = img
```

This is wrong. You must create image where all pixels will be zero (black).

Comment: after 4-5 line there is 'res = np.zeros(img.shape)'